Using cookies storage on Next.js app with Amplify Auth
I am currently creating a website with Next.js where I am using Amplify to authenticate my users. But the problem is that Amplify stores user's session including tokens on browser's localStorage which I think is not secure.
Is it more secure to use cookiesStorage instead and how can I configure Amplify to store user's session in cookiesStorage

For Amplify Gen 2
You can set ssr: true in the library options when you configure amplify to use cookies instead.
Amplify.configure(outputs, {
  ssr: true // required when using Amplify with Next.js
});


NOTE: To use the Amplify library on the client side in a Next.js app, you will need to set ssr to true when calling Amplify.configure. This instructs the Amplify library to store tokens in the cookie store of a browser. Cookies will be sent along with requests to your Next.js server for authentication.

Reference - Configure Amplify library for client-side usage
For Amplify Gen 1
You can update the storage mechanism to choose where and how tokens are persisted in your application. The default option is localStorage. Additionally, you can import the sessionStorage, sharedInMemoryStorage or CookieStorage options as well.
To save tokens in cookie, use below line of code.
cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(new CookieStorage());

Here is the complete code example.
import { Amplify, type ResourcesConfig } from 'aws-amplify';
import { CookieStorage } from 'aws-amplify/utils';
import { cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider } from 'aws-amplify/auth/cognito';

const authConfig: ResourcesConfig['Auth'] = {
  Cognito: {
    userPoolId: 'your_user_pool_id',
    userPoolClientId: 'your_user_pool_client_id'
  }
};

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: authConfig
});

cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(new CookieStorage());

You can read more about it at Understand token management options.

I am using Gen 1 on my project. I set ssr to true but it still saves the data in localStorage

@Besart - I have updated the answer, added what needs to be done in Gen1 to enable cookie storage for auth tokens.
